# Get Value from JSON for a given Key where parent key names are dynamic

Tags: javascript, jquery, json

I have a json string which starts like this:

```
{ "0" : 
{"Jquery77768" : 
    {"nodeData": 
        {"id":32, "name": "Bob"}
        ----
```

I need to get the value which is there in the `id` key.
I tried to do something like this:

```
var obj = JSON.parse(myJsonString);
var myID = obj[0].Jquery77768.nodeData.id;
```

but this does not work. Also the second node name `Jquery77768` is dynamic and will change every time.

How can I get the value of the `id` field?

Comment: Your code appears to work fine: https://jsfiddle.net/RoryMcCrossan/hxbk6o4L/

Comment: you can use [] operator to access "Jquery77768" element: ```obj[0]["Jquery77768"].nodeData.id```, so you can put Jquery77768 dynamically

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan — It stops working when the property name `Jquery77768` changes (as the question says it does).

Comment: @user2244399 - They can, and they can use dot notation as they are using already, but **that doesn't help** because they don't know what the value should be.

Comment: So the question then becomes how do they determine what that key *should* be? Accessing the object is trivial after that. @Quentin the reason I posted my original comment was because the OP states that the code doesn't work as-is. The dynamic property name was an addendum to that.

Comment: Yes the property name changes dynamically and it will not be known in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you mentioned dynamic key names (Jquery77768), It will be better to get the `Object.values`. (Assuming one key as in data).

```
var myID = Object.values(obj["0"])[0].nodeData.id;
```

Comment: A lump of code completely free of any explanation as to how it solves the problem isn't very helpful.

Answer (score 0):

What about a general function ? But suppose order of keys may not be same everywhere...

```js
var obj = '{ "0" : {"Jquery77768" : {"nodeData": {"id":32, "name": "Bob"} }}}';
obj = JSON.parse(obj);
console.log(goDownNth(obj[0], 1).nodeData.id);
console.log(goDownNth(obj[0], 1).nodeData.id === goDownNth(goDownNth(goDownNth(goDownNth(obj, 1), 1), 1), 1));
console.log(goDownNth(goDownNth(goDownNth(goDownNth(obj, 1), 1), 1), 2));

function goDownNth (obj, n) {
    for (var a in obj) {
        if (!--n) return obj[a];
    }
}
```